# Изменения на сайте битрикс видны только под администратором

Tags: битрикс

Первый раз работаю с 1с битрикс. Правлю стилевой и джс-файл, при этом изменения видно только после авторизации под админом. Неавторизованные пользователи не видят изменения. Кеширование отключил, cdn в норме, каждый раз чищу кеш через настройки в админке - не помогает.

Comment: в смысле - "после авторизации"? а как Вы их правите будучи неавторизованным?

Comment: Правлю то после авторизации) но изменения видят только авторизованные и больше никто, в этом проблема

Comment: А кеш Вы как очищаете? Попробуйте так: Настройки -> Настройки продукта -> Автокеширование -> Очистка файлов кеша -> Все

Comment: так и делал, но прошел день и все само собой заработало, все таки какая та трабла с кешем

Answer (score 1):

Как вы подключаете JS и стилевые фаилы?

Для этого в API битрикса существуют специальные методы, лучше использовтаь их.

```
<?
// для js-файлов
$APPLICATION->AddHeadScript('/bitrix/templates/.default/additional.js');

// для css-файлов
$APPLICATION->SetAdditionalCSS("/bitrix/templates/.default/additional.css");
?>
```

Если же вы подключаете через тег  то измените имя фаила JS на любое другое а потом обновите кэш, как делали до этого.
или добавьте версионность как в примере ниже

```
<script src="/js/main.js?123456789"></script>
```

Comment: Так подключено `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=CUtil::GetAdditionalFileURL(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/custom.css")?> $APPLICATION->AddHeadScript(SITE_TEMPLATE_PATH."/script.js");`

Comment: попробуй переименовать в script1.js custom1.css - иногда такое срабатывает

Comment: спасибо за совет. На данный момент все норм, вчера к вечеру само собой заработало )